# mySQL: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost" after installing the software

Tags: mysql, linux

I have just installed mySQL 5.1.55 on a Linux box, and it seems to be ok

```
# /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_install_db
Installing MySQL system tables...
160606 21:46:25 [Warning] '--skip-locking' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--skip-external-locking' instead.
OK
Filling help tables...
160606 21:46:26 [Warning] '--skip-locking' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--skip-external-locking' instead.
OK

To start mysqld at boot time you have to copy
support-files/mysql.server to the right place for your system

PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MySQL root USER !
To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:

/usr/local/mysql-5.1.55/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'

Alternatively you can run:
/usr/local/mysql-5.1.55/bin/mysql_secure_installation

which will also give you the option of removing the test
databases and anonymous user created by default.  This is
strongly recommended for production servers.

See the manual for more instructions.

You can start the MySQL daemon with:
cd /usr/local/mysql-5.1.55 ; /usr/local/mysql-5.1.55/bin/mysqld_safe &

You can test the MySQL daemon with mysql-test-run.pl
cd /usr/local/mysql-5.1.55/mysql-test ; perl mysql-test-run.pl

Please report any problems with the /usr/local/mysql-5.1.55/bin/mysqlbug script!
```

However, if I run

```
# /usr/local/mysql-5.1.55/bin/mysqladmin -u root password foo
```

I get this error message:

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.1.55/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

If I run:

```
# /usr/local/mysql-5.1.55/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

I am not able to figure out which the password is :-S

Any help is welcome. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed mysql without running

```
> mysql_secure_installation
```

script there should be no password at all. Just type

```
> mysql
```

and see what happens. If that fails you can still set a new root password following the [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)